# Why is my cordyline superstar’s leaves falling off?

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, leaves, watering

Someone lent me a cordyline superstar for the holidays. I don’t know if I gave it the right amount of water (2 glasses each 3 days) but the soil is humid.

The problem is that now the base of the leaves are really fragile and they fall off. 3 of them have fallen since yesterday because I touched them, but the rest of the remaining leaves are already half torn from the trunk. 2 of the falling leaves were not dried out though. One of them had its base brown, viscous and a little stinky. Another one was dried out, really crispy, and the last one was normal. They were all from the bottom of the plant. I linked some pictures in this post.

Also, there is a lot of flies around my plant.

Since it’s the first plant that I have, I don’t know what to do to help it and I don’t know exactly what caused it. Thanks for helping!

Leaf 1:[image]

Leaf 2: [image]

The whole plant: [image]

The bottom of it: [image]

Comment: Are there drainage holes in the pot?

Comment: Yes, there are at least 8